# What are the most useful third party iPhone frameworks?

Tags: iphone, frameworks

What really super useful third party frameworks / toolkits / projects are out there that people have used and have found to be a huge help in building their iPhone apps?  Bonus points if you include a story about how it helped you on a real world project.

I'll go first:

- [cocos2d](http://cocos2d.org/index.html)
- [JSON.framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/)
- [AQToolkit](http://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit)

EDIT: turned this community wiki

Comment: Sounds like you are keen on reputation xD

Answer (score 3):

I would add the following for social networking support:

- Twitter API: [MGTwitterEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/source)
- [Facebook Connect](http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone)

Answer (score 3):

- [Three20](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/)
- [ASIHTTPRequest](http://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/)

Answer (score 1):

[Objective Resource](http://iphoneonrails.com/) lets you connect an iPhone app to a rails app.

Answer (score 0):

While some of the frameworks listed are Mac-only, the question ["What open source Cocoa/Cocoa Touch Frameworks are out there?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501981/what-open-source-cocoa-cocoa-touch-frameworks-are-out-there) has links to many quality third-party frameworks in the answers.  Of those, I've used [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) within our robotic control software to simplify the addition of scatter plots (of course, I'm a little biased, being one of the contributors to the project).