# iPhone Frameworks

Tags: iphone

What is a strong iPhone framework to start out developing with, besides the SDK from Apple? Are there any that exist to speed up development time?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492600/what-are-the-most-useful-third-party-iphone-frameworks

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this in my search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest framework of this kind is [Three20](http://three20.info/). Facebook and many other companies use this. Three20 is geared towards apps that pull data from the web. It helps with common patterns like a photo viewer or table view backed by web data. Another neat feature is that it has stylesheets, similar in concept to CSS.

Having said all that, some people like it and some do not. There was a brief period where apps using it were rejected from the App Store. Overall, the project looks to have improved since then.

Answer (score 2):

[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

Excerpt

> It is suitable performing basic HTTP
>   requests and interacting with
>   REST-based services (GET / POST / PUT
>   / DELETE). The included
>   ASIFormDataRequest subclass makes it
>   easy to submit POST data and files
>   using multipart/form-data.

Also,

[skpsmtpmessage](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/)

Excerpt

> This code implements a quick class for
>   sending one off messages via SMTP on
>   the iPhone

**EDIT**:

**A quick google search gave me this** [link](http://iphoneized.com/2009/11/18-mobile-frameworks-development-tools-creating-iphone-apps/)

Answer (score 0):

There is [Mono Touch](http://monotouch.net/) which enables you to develop using C#.